# Is there a more formal phrase or word for "practice what you preach?"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

I am trying to think of a non-colloquial word or phrase that means "practice what you preach." I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: "Consistency" comes to mind, but it seems broader than what you're looking for.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. How do you want to use the word in a sentence? Please refer to the single-word-request tag (hover your mouse over it) and also to its [Question Checklist](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: "Do unto others" aka "The Golden Rule."  There are also enjoinders to not be a *hypocrite.*

Answer (score 3):

"Lead by example" comes to mind.

FROM COMMENT BELOW: In my own upbringing, adults often told children "You should lead by example" as a way of instilling values and character. I recall hearing this in school, in the Catholic Church, the Boy Scouts of America, and the various leadership training programs that my parents sent me to. As an adult, I have frequently heard the phrase in business management contexts, where executives are expected to lead by example, all of which strikes me as a more formal (and less critical) method of conveying a similar meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Any **principled** or **righteous** person, even though they do not actively 'preach', advertise their values by sticking to them.

Precisely what we like about this type of people is that they do not preach; if they started doing so, then they would become **self-righteous**, **sanctimonious**, **holier-than-thou**.

'Practice what you preach' is used negatively, mostly, to reproach people for not doing it/so. (As I hesitated between 'it' and 'so', I googled the two structures, which sent me back to StackExchange ELU but not to a satisfactory explanation of why one should use one or the other!)

[cambridge dictionaries online's definition of 'principled'](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/principled)

Answer (score 0):

A less metaphorical phrase that means the same thing as 'practice what you preach' is

> suit your actions to your words.

The phrase has been elaborated in literature. In the eponymous play (Act III, Scene 2) by Shakespeare, Hamlet advises a troupe of actors to

> *Suit the action to the word, the word to the action*, with this special observance, that you o'erstep not the modesty of nature.

The more colloquial, less proverbial phrase than 'practice what you preach', 'walk the talk', draws its definition from the straightforward phrasing in [*The Oxford Dictionary of Idioms* (ed. Judith Siefring, 2004, second edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019852711X):

> **walk your (or the) talk** *suit your actions to your words*, informal, chiefly North American.

Answer (score 0):

"Practice what you preach" is already rather formal, IMHO. I don't think many people under 30 would say it.