# Is there an expression in English for "being asked to act on your own suggestion"?

Tags: proverbs, proverb-requests

Is there an expression in English for "being asked to act on your own suggestion"?

Here's an example of the scenario that I'm thinking about:

> Wife: Husband, the living room light is broken. We need to buy a new one.
>   Husband: Sure, honey. When you go to the market today, could you buy a new light?

Comment: Two ideas: Getting a taste of your own medicine. He who smelt it, dealt it.

Comment: I don't see why this is necessarily a problem at all. What if the wife is simply asking if it's okay for her to spend money on a new light? Or if she's asking because he might have an opinion as to what type of light to buy (which he clearly doesn't). Without additional context, I don't see the necessary correlation to any particular type of proverb.

Comment: I think @YosefBaskin you provided the answer I was looking for. If you could give it as an answer, I can accept it

Comment: @JasonBassford I believe the husband is just being "playful" with his wife.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a more formal phrase or word for "practice what you preach?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/309894/is-there-a-more-formal-phrase-or-word-for-practice-what-you-preach) ('Walk the talk'; 'Lead by example'.)

Answer (score 0):

**A taste of your own medicine** is an idiom for *returning the favor* when there was no favor to begin with.

The standard use is the **payback for bad advice, hints, or actions**.

- An Aesop fable has it that a snake oil salesman is given his own
  useless cure-all when he falls ill. If the townspeople know how
  useless medicine is, that is a prime example of giving him a taste of
  his own medicine.
- One unattractive example is the dog owner who rubs the dog’s nose in
  the doggie doo, as a *teaching moment*. After Fido drops some
  offering on the living room floor, the owner repays Fido by implying
  “If you think your contribution is welcome, how do you like it when I
  return the favor?” That message is the taste of Fido’s own medicine.
  For some reason, this educational tool has fallen out of fashion.
- In the original example of husband and wife, the wife’s comment that
  “we need to buy” a new light may be neutral, while the husband takes
  it as a manipulation. And he thinks that if she converted “we need to
  buy” into “you need to buy,” he can just as well give her a taste of
  her own medicine by saying that *she needs to buy a light*. We do not
  actually know that is all true from her remark alone, but he thinks so.

[Here's a taste of your own medicine.](https://theidioms.com/taste-of-own-medicine/)

Answer (score 0):

An emerging phrase, or at least a meme, would be to say that the husband ["pulled an uno reverse card,"](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/uno-reverse-card) on the wife, because she was implying that the husband needed to take action, but she did not explicitly state that, so the husband took the opportunity to ["turn the tables"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+the+tables) on her.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with "a taste of your own medicine" as being appropriate here, because it implies a level of [revenge](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/evolution-the-self/201901/should-you-give-someone-taste-their-own-medicine) or, at the very least, a well-earned negative result against the "taster." A husband who asks his wife to take her own advice isn't being aggressive (though perhaps a bit stand-offish).

A better phrase for this is to [*"practice what you preach"*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/practice+what+you+preach), which means to do whatever action you're suggesting of others.

> Wife: Husband, the living room light is broken. We need to buy a new one.
> Husband: Sure, honey. You're going to the market today-- practice what you preach and buy a new light.

Comment: Personally I'm not sure "practice what you preach" carries a perfect connotation either, as usually the "preaching" is done on multiple occasions, not just a single event. Also, if the husband included that it would turn his response from playful banter towards a passive aggressive response.

Comment: @TylerN Agreed, but I can't think of any way the husband might use the phrase "taste of your own medicine" in this context that wouldn't be even worse.